# How did Rocket know how to extract the Reality Stone?

Tags: plot-explanation, marvel-cinematic-universe, avengers-endgame, thor-the-dark-world

In the movie *Thor: The Dark World* we come to know that once the **Reality Stone** (*Aether*) has taken a living being's body as a carrier host, it is extremely difficult to extract it. When *Jane Foster* asks *Odin* about whether or not his books tell him how to extract it, he says that information is unavailable:

> Jane Foster: Does your book happen to mention how to get it out of me?

> Odin: No, it does not.

We have been told that the *Asgardians* are a very old race, *Thor* alone being 1500+ years old (as he himself tells us in *Infinity War*):

> Thor: You know, I'm 1,500 years old

Thus, it may be safely presumed that *Asgardians* are much older than many other space beings in the MCU.

So, the question is, how come *Rocket* extract the **Reality Stone** with a handheld device (in *Avengers: Endgame*), when even the great *Odin* had no clue how to do it?

Comment: If you don't know how to do something, you don't know how to do it. Rocket is quite the tech god as it were.

Comment: Just an observation: the Asgardians previously had no need to find out, as Odin's father had (seemingly) disposed of it, and a very short window to act. The Avengers however, had as long as they wanted to research and prepare for the heist.